# How to implement loop and calculate the value in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

As a php beginner, I meet a problem with calculating the elements of array in php

```
$effect=array("a"=>array(1,2),"b"=>array(1,2),"c"=>array(1,2));
```

I just want to make the result as this

```
$effect['a'][0]=$effect['a'][0]/$effect['a'][1];
$effect['b'][0]=$effect['b'][0]/$effect['b'][1]; 
$effect['c'][0]=$effect['c'][0]/$effect['c'][1];
```

Except do this one by one , How to do this calculation with **foreach** or other loop way

Comment: So your goal is to divide the first element of each sub-array by the second element of the first sub-array?

Comment: sorry I have made a little mistake ,my goal is to divide the first element of each sub-array by the second element of each sub-array

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sorry I have made a little mistake , and i have modified the index:my goal is to divide the first element of each sub-array by the second element of each sub-array

Answer (score 1):

Your array syntax is a bit off. It should be `$effect['a'][0]`.

The loop is trivial, and [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) was the right idea.
You can use it to iterate over all the letters using:

```
 foreach ($effect as $letter => $numbers) {

     ...

 }
```

Then put your assignment/division line in the loop, replacing the fixed `'a'` and `'b'` etc. with the `$letter` variable.

Comment: Is there any difference with what i have written ?"Your array syntax is a bit off. It should be $effect['a'][0]."

Comment: Your original post used `$effect('a')[0]`, which is why I noted that.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this?

```
foreach ($effect as $key => $val)
{

    $results[$key] = $val[0] / $val[1];

}

print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also one counter-intuitive thing in PHP, is that arrays are passed by value by default. You can use & to get a reference to the array

```
$effects =array("a"=>array(1,2),"b"=>array(1,2),"c"=>array(1,2));
foreach ( $effects as $key => &$effect ) {
   $effect[0] = $effect[0]/$effect[1];
   unset($effect);
}
print_r( $effects );
```